# How to Emulate a Cmd Shell Command(i.e. "cd") and Effect the State of the Command Prompt on Exit

Tags: windows, command-line, command, command-prompt

I would like to emulate the standard command line prompt command "CD" to create an extended version that, for example, provides a search capability. My research has not led me to a way to change the current directory path of a host shell.

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: This question is specific to the Windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite murky how the command interpreter's CD command would do anything to enhance a 'search capability'.  Starting one with the right 'CD' directory isn't difficult.  Just use CreateProcess to start cmd.exe.  The lpCurrentDirectory argument lets you set the current directory.  ShellExecuteEx() works too, a bit easier to get right.

Comment: The basic idea is to permit wildcards when moving to another directory. An example might be to go from C:\ to C:\Program Files with a command such as "CX pr*". The command would search the directory tree for a match (both up and down) until a match is found. Matches would provide prompts to the user to accept and make the change. I've tried CreateProcess() but it spawns a new command prompt window with the correct path but would not work for me. I've seen simple utilities with a GUI that presents a path selection that can make the change so it looks to be possible.

Comment: I haven't got a clue what you are talking about.  Just press the TAB key in a console mode window and it autocompletes a file name fragment.